# Adding functions as properties including a this value

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue adding a function containing `this` to an object. It is producing results that I did not expect, and that have left me somewhat confused. I tried rewriting the code using `Object.create()` and that just threw an error. I must be overlooking something simple I am sure. How do I ensure that `qaz.execute` is implicitly bound to `qaz`? Thank you for your help.

```
// Version 1:
var qaz = {}; // [[Prototype]] will point to Object.prototype.
qaz.execute = function(){ console.log( "qaz: " + this ) };
qaz.execute(); // qaz: [object Object] (Why not qaz or even global/undefined?)

// Version 2:
var qaz = Object.create(null); // [[Prototype]] will be null.
qaz.execute = function(){ console.log( "qaz: " + this ) };
qaz.execute(); // TypeError: can't convert this to primitive type (Why?)
```

Comment: What did you expect logging an object to display?

Comment: So you're adding an object to a string?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Yes, I see why this doesn't work now. Is there a way to log the current value of this to the console?

Comment: Yes, just `console.log(this)`, it works for both. The last one won't stringify because you didn't inherit `toString`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. This has cleared it up perfectly.

Comment: `qaz.execute = function(){ console.log( "qaz: ", this ); };` Depending on your browser you should not log objects as strings unless you're using IE as that browser is unable to log an object in any kind of useful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Version 2:
var qaz = Object.create(null); // [[Prototype]] will be null.
qaz.execute = function(){ console.log( "qaz: " + this ) };
qaz.execute(); // TypeError: can't convert this to primitive type (Why?)
```

Because quz does not inherit toString from Object.prototype. You could do the following:

```
var qaz = Object.create(null); // [[Prototype]] will be null.
qaz.execute = function(){ console.log( "qaz: " + 
Object.prototype.toString(this) ); };
qaz.execute();
```

Or as stated in my and elclanrs comment; not convert the object to string at all and log object as is (probably doesn't work in IE):

```
var qaz = Object.create(null); // [[Prototype]] will be null.
qaz.execute = function(){ console.log( "qaz: ", this); };
qaz.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish. I'd recommend taking a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#this_on_the_object's_prototype_chain

It should give you a better grasp on `this`

Near as I can tell, if you want to log what exactly qaz is, try this instead

```
var qaz = {}; 
qaz.execute = function(){ return this };
console.log("qaz: " + qaz.execute());
```

it will not, however, print "qaz", but it will, i think, print all of qaz's properties. 
If you want to learn more about outputting stuff to the console, read here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console